# Sliding Mode Control for fluid mechanical system - How to find the control law?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, simulation, lyapunov-functions

Assume that we have a water tank system:

$$A \dot h = Q_\text{in} - Q_\text{out} = Q_\text{in} - a\sqrt{2gh} $$

Where $a$ is the opening area in the bottom of the water tank and $\sqrt{2gh}$ is the velocity for the outflow and $h$ is the water level height. The $A$ is the area of the water tank bottom. $A \dot h$ will therefor be the change in volume for the water tank.

If $a = 0$ then the $A \dot h$ is going to increase. If $a > 0$ then $A \dot h$ is going to decrease.

The sliding mode controller can be designed in this way:

$$S = ek + \dot e = 0$$

[image]

Where $k$ is a slope and $e$ is the error $e = r - h$ where $r$ is the reference point.

Sliding Mode Control use the signum formula:

$$\sigma = \operatorname{sgn}(ek + \dot e)$$

where $\sigma$ can be $1$ or $-1$ depending where the trajectory is.

But then I need to have some proportional scalar.

**Question:**

How do I find the propotional tuning factor for this? Can I just add a P-controller with $\sigma$?

$$u = Ke\sigma$$

where $K$ is a gain factor and $e$ is the error. The problem is that this controller is a linear controller.

Is there a way to describe that system in Lyapunov control theory with $\sigma$?

Or can the controller look like this:

$$u = \frac{Q_{in}-A\dot h}{\sqrt{2gh}}e\sigma $$

When $h=0$ then $u$ is very large. 
When $\dot h = 0$ it means $e = 0$ and then $ u=0$.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sliding mode control, controller dynamics are mainly determined with the error dynamics. So an error dynamics like in

$$
\sigma(K_1,K_2) = \mbox{sign}(K_1e+K_2 \dot e)
$$

have two actions

1) $K_1e$ proportional

2) $K_2\dot e$ derivative

The main problem in slide mode control is the so called chattering effect.

Comment: Yes. But the signum will only result negative one or positive one. How about tune in the nonlinear gain? I choose the SMC control for fluid dynamics because it's difficult to create a dynamical model for fluids and SMC taking account to uncertainites in modeling. Very robust, but vibrerating. Perfect for fluids.